# is there a way to change the default output file from avi to mp4 in directshow?

Tags: c#, directshow, mp4, avi

it is already generating avi file format, i want to change the output format

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any way to record video from webcam in mp4 format ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633560/is-there-any-way-to-record-video-from-webcam-in-mp4-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install MP4 muxer and use it instead of AVI Mux. Google for "MP4 Muxer" to find them. For start:
http://www.3ivx.com/technology/filters/media_muxer.html
http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/

Comment: Register in the system using "regsvr32 filename". Add to graph by its GUID instead of AVI Mux.